# sql how to use this syntax more light weight?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello i'm getting this message:

```
[The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay]
```

on this syntax:

```
    SELECT CONCAT(v2.meta_value, ' ', v3.meta_value) AS name,
 a.usr, a.vagtDato, b.timeloen, c.provision, d.kursus, e.trappetur, f.sygedag
FROM $main_table a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT usr, count(vagt_type) as timeloen
FROM $main_table  WHERE vagt_type = 'timeloen'
AND vagtDato between DATE('$start') AND DATE('$end')
GROUP BY usr ) b on b.usr=a.usr

LEFT JOIN (SELECT usr, count(vagt_type) as provision
FROM $main_table  WHERE vagt_type = 'provision'
AND vagtDato between DATE('$start') AND DATE('$end')
GROUP BY usr ) c on c.usr=a.usr

LEFT JOIN (SELECT usr, count(vagt_type) as kursus
FROM $main_table  WHERE vagt_type = 'kursus'
AND vagtDato between DATE('$start') AND DATE('$end')
GROUP BY usr ) d on d.usr=a.usr

LEFT JOIN (SELECT usr, count(vagt_type) as trappetur
FROM $main_table  WHERE vagt_type = 'trappetur'
AND vagtDato between DATE('$start') AND DATE('$end')
GROUP BY usr ) e on e.usr=a.usr

LEFT JOIN (SELECT usr, count(vagt_type) as sygedag
FROM $main_table  WHERE vagt_type = 'sygedag'
AND vagtDato between DATE('$start') AND DATE('$end')
GROUP BY usr ) f on f.usr=a.usr

LEFT JOIN Lausten_usermeta v2 ON a.usr=v2.user_id and v2.meta_key = 'first_name'
LEFT JOIN Lausten_usermeta v3 ON a.usr=v3.user_id and v3.meta_key = 'last_name'

WHERE a.vagtDato between DATE('$start') AND DATE('$end')
GROUP BY a.usr
ORDER BY $orderby $order LIMIT %d OFFSET %d
```

so i know that i can set a higher limit but i'd like to aviod that!

is there a way to make this syntax more light weight?

Comment: I would consider using an SQL pivot, to pivot the vagt_type values into columns.

Comment: Or group by usr AND vagt_type? Might be easier to determine a better query if you shared some sample data and expected results?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation for the subqueries:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT usr,
                  sum(vagt_type = 'timeloen') as timeloen,
                  sum(vagt_type = 'provision') as provision,
                  . . .
           FROM $main_table 
           WHERE vagtDato between DATE('$start') AND DATE('$end')
           GROUP BY usr
          ) b
          on b.usr = a.usr
```

This will replace all the subqueries with just one.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're working with multiple [Entity-Attribute-Value tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), which are useful, but also a huge relational nightmare.  You may wish to consider creating views for the EAV tables you commonly use to make your life a bit easier.

That said, you could do this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(v.meta_value, ' ', v.meta_value) AS NAME
    ,a.usr
    ,a.vagtDato
    ,b.timeloen
    ,b.provision
    ,b.kursus
    ,b.trappetur
    ,b.sygedag
FROM $MAIN_TABLE a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT usr
        ,sum(case when vagt_type = 'timeloen'  then 1 else 0 end) as timeloen
        ,sum(case when vagt_type = 'provision' then 1 else 0 end) as provision
        ,sum(case when vagt_type = 'kursus'    then 1 else 0 end) as kursus
        ,sum(case when vagt_type = 'trappetur' then 1 else 0 end) as trappetur
        ,sum(case when vagt_type = 'sygedag'   then 1 else 0 end) as sygedag
    FROM $MAIN_TABLE
    WHERE vagt_type IN ('timeloen','provision','kursus','trappetur','sygedag')
        AND vagtDato BETWEEN DATE ('$start') AND DATE ('$end')
    GROUP BY usr
    ) b
    ON b.usr = a.usr
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id
        ,max(case when meta_key = 'first_name' then meta_value else null end) as first_name
        ,max(case when meta_key = 'last_name'  then meta_value else null end) as last_name
    FROM Lausten_usermeta
    GROUP BY user_id
    ) v
    ON v.user_id = a.usr
WHERE a.vagtDato BETWEEN DATE ('$start') AND DATE ('$end')
GROUP BY a.usr
ORDER BY $ORDERBY $ORDER LIMIT %d OFFSET %d
```

Beyond that, it's virtually impossible to tell what you might be able to do since it's hard to tell what your data actually looks like (especially what your primary keys are) and what results you actually need.